# Does Japa wipes good karma also

Tags: belief, gods, karma

I know or having belief that japa can wipe out bad karmas we deed knowing or unknowingly in past or present life.

But going through one of the website, i came accross information that :

Japa not only cleans bad karma but also cleans effects of good karma so that we dont have to take birth again to enjoy the effects of good karma.

Wanted to know is it true philosophy???

Comment: its more complicated than simply 'wiping out karmas'. That is a very simplistic explanation. Karma is nothing but action and reaction, what you sow, so you reap. The qualification that it is Good karma and bad karma occur because of attachment. When one gets what one wants, it becomes a good karma, when one gets what one does not want it becomes a bad karma. Sadhana and japa providesthe platform to obtain detachment. If the sadhaka has no wants, then whatever happens, just happens, there is nothing good or bad. This is vairagya. It leads to realization. It can be obtained by japa. All the best

Comment: @Sai  "When one gets what one wants ...  when one gets what one does not want ... " is it karma or effect of karma?? when one gets whatever he wants is it self a 'good karma' or effect of good karma and does not gets whatever he wants is 'bad karma ' or effect of bad karma done by him ???

Comment: The scriptures may say one who performs Japa, Namasankirtana can attain liberation - What exactly it means is that by doing Japa, namasankirtana one gets cleansed of papa karmas, which will allow us to meditate on Brahman and perform saranagathi to the Lord and attain  liberation eventually. Both good and papa karmas should be removed, to get liberation.

Comment: @Krishna  There we are creating confusion ... Both good and bad karmas should be removed to get liberated , but does japa removes only bad karma as you mentioned in above paragraph??(namasankirtana one gets cleansed of papa karmas)

Comment: @C.Ronaldo What I mean is good and bad come out of attachment or desire. It applies to both action and effect. Those actions which you think will produce pleasurable results, you deem good actions. Those actions which you think will produce painful results, you deem bad actions. Similar with effects, when something good happens to you, you exclaim "What good karma have I done :)" and when something bad happens to you, you exclaim "What bad have I done to deserve this!". Suppose you have no such desires or wants. Then even if one loses his job, still he remains happy. Thus good & bad 'wiped'.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/good-karma-gives-fruits-in-this-life-or-next-life

Comment: @Krishna Are you saying that it's necessary to be cleansed of Papa Karmas before you undertake Saranagati/Prapatti?  It may be necessary for Bhakti Yoga, but not for Saranagati.  Isn't the whole point of the Charama Shloka of the Bhagavad Gita that if you do Saranagati, then Vishnu will cleanse you of your Papa Karmas?

Comment: @Keshav - No, i didnt mean that papa karmas shouldnt exist before saranagati. As per my understanding, Saranagati, which is conisidered sadyopayam, removes not just agami karmas but sanchitta karma also. Prarabdha karma still exists, which will be removed only after one sheds his or her mortal coils. That doesn't mean it gives a licence to do papa karmas. Unintentional wrong doing will be pardoned by the Lord, but for intentional ones, one will be given punishments by the Lord, in this birth itself, as per Rahasyatraya saaram of Swami Vedanta Desikar.

Comment: @Krishna This means do we get punishment for all bad karmas in this life only?? Then by child borns disabled??? why one gets alcoholic parents?? why one faces misfortune everytime even after doing so many good karmas in this life?

Comment: @Ronaldo- The above comment i made was for those who have done complete self surrender to the Lord. Even then prarabdha karma would remain is my understanding, till one gives up one's mortal coils. For other questions, i am not qualified to answer. One needs to approach a bonafide acharya to understand and gain his grace and Lord's Grace.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/what-happens-with-karma-with-expectations-of-fruits

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/punishment-for-bad-karma-after-death-also-and-after-new-getting-new-body-also

Comment: @Sagar You might be interested in my answer to a related question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/does-chanting-holy-names-while-doing-worldly-duties-generate-any-punya-karma

Comment: @AmitSaxena yeah , nice answer , Question you pointed is question by me only :)

Comment: @Sagar lol ya, for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Japam in and of itself does not wipe out good karma. What Japam does is purify the body and soul. Sarada Devi, the holy consort of Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said:

> As wind removes the cloud, so the Name of God destroys the cloud of worldliness...Do you know the significance of Japa and other spiritual practices? By these, the power of the sense organs is subdued...One has to suffer the consequences of one's deeds. But by repeating the Name of God, you can lessen its intensity...The effect of karma can be counteracted to a great extent by Japa and austerities...Japa will eventually bring spiritual realization.

By subduing the sense organs, realization comes. The Katha Upanishad (II. iii. 14-15.) says:

> 14. When all the desires that dwell in the heart fall away, then the mortal becomes immortal and here attains Brahman.
> 15. When all the ties of the heart are severed here on earth, then the mortal becomes immortal. This much alone is the teaching.

Many people want to get rid of the effects of bad karma, but good karma can bind one to rebirth also. Thus when all desires, good and bad, and all ties of the heart, good and bad, are wiped out the soul is purified. When the soul is purified, then realization comes and both good and bad karmas are wiped out. Good karma, just as bad karma, lies within the realm of maya.

Krishna says in the Gita (II. 50.) "Endued with evenness of mind, one casts off, in this very life, both good deeds and evil deeds. Therefore strive for yoga. Yoga is skill in action."

Comment: Maharaj , I have read on internet , If one does the japa while doing any karma then that karma becomes "Akarma" means person does not gets the good or bad effects of that karma. Is that mean if i do any bad karma (murder someone [just for example]) while chanting holy name, then i will not get its bad effects or will not suffer ??

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/is-there-time-place-or-method-of-chanting-holy-name

Comment: maharaj please answer above comment also

Comment: The Lord is no fool. If you are committing a murder with a tamasic attitude and have no remorse in your heart and are simply doing Japa to try and lessen the karma, then no, it will not. If you are, on the other hand, doing what is your karma that cannot be avoided and your heart is crying to the Lord for mercy, then yes, Japa will lessen the effects.

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/good-karma-gives-fruits-in-this-life-or-next-life

Comment: @Swamiji please answer : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/what-happens-with-karma-with-expectations-of-fruits

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/punishment-for-bad-karma-after-death-also-and-after-new-getting-new-body-also