# Can i chant nama of lord Rama without initiation?

Tags: rama, initiation

Is it ok to chant ramanama without initiation?
I am chanting without initiation until now.

Is it ok to chant ramanama without tulasi beads?

Comment: Apparently Nama-japa does not require initiation .. see this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20169/does-nama-japa-also-require-diksha-initiation

Comment: I have heard that one cannot use om with other mantras without talking initiation. Is it true?

Comment: That is what the scriptures usually say @aniketkumarsingh

Comment: Ok thanks guys@Rickross

Comment: But should i do with or without beads? @Rickross

Comment: Its better u count using beads @Learner

Comment: But if u know the method of counting using fingers then u can avoid using Japamala but using Japamala is the usual thing. @Learner