anusthan vs purascharana
To attend mantra siddhi(realising the deity), one has to do purasharana(x japa, x/10 homa, x/100 tarpana, x/1000 marjana, x/10000 bhojanam).
Even in many references they are saying about anusthana, which is looking similar.
Questions:

Are purascharana and anusthana same?

Naam japa can have purascharana/anusthna ?


Reference:

Purascharana for stotras?
What is Purascharana and how is it done?


About nama japa we can't be even sure if Diksha is required or not .. so purascharana and the allied homa etc won't be needed.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20169/4732
