# What happens with karma with expectations of fruits?

Tags: karma, bhagavad-gita

With the reference to famous shlok in Bhagwat Gita :

One should do karma without expectations of fruits in return.

But what happens if I make all good karmas with the expectations of good will come in return to me?

Does that karma becomes void? Or will it definitely give me good fruits one or another time?

Comment: if you do karma with expectation of fruits, then those good fruits you will certainly get. But be assured, that it will not bring you permanent happiness (you refers to everyone). Ask yourself, "Why do I desire these good results?'. The answer, if you keep questioning, will finally be 'because it makes me happy'. Then the self-enquiry starts, what is it that really makes you happy? The answer will be 'There is nothing that makes me happy, for I am happiness itself. I am That Atman which is Truth, Consciousness and Bliss itself'. All the best

Comment: @Sai http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/punishment-for-bad-karma-after-death-also-and-after-new-getting-new-body-also

Comment: The fruits will bring temporary pleasantness rather than permanent joy. We cannot fill the hole we feel—the desire for more—with the material. Desiring more necessarily means that you feel "not enough." Understanding your unity with all other things the feeling goes from "I don't have enough" to "I am everything; there's so much that I need to give to others." By focusing on the fruits and observing that they don't lead to transcendent joy, you can learn to stop focusing on fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No karma becomes void unless truth is realized. Hence for mortals like us this option does not arise.

Now coming to your fundamental question, karmas can be divided into many categories like nishkama karma, kamya karma etc. Karma associated with your question falls under Kamya karma which means a person desires something from his karma. No issues from doing such karma, instead its good too but not the best because Nishkama karma is the best. If good deeds are done, definitively good fruits will come to you, but might not be always as below example illustrates.

Example:Person X goes to office with a sweet box. On the way, in road he sees a poor man Y who is about to die. Feeling pity on him, X gives a sweet and then goes. After eating sweet, Y dies as he was suffering from acute diabetes. Now X did a good karma with good intention but result was not good. 
Hence a person must do Karmas without desires. Also karmas done without desires purify your mind and will help in spiritual progress.

Sources:According to book "eternal laws" (published by Sringeri Mutt publications)

Comment: In the illustration you given does X man has to go from sufferings also as the poor man has died???

Comment: No. X will will not get huge punishment for his karma. Because
1) Y got diabetes and died to enjoy his own karma. X's role here was just a lila. A small role to play.
2) Hence X will get a karma in a small way. May be something like eating a sweet given by his friend and getting stomach upset.(Just an example)

Comment: Thinking bad about someone who is doing bad with you is bad karma??? just thinking???

Comment: Thinking doesnt involve harm. No one can be arrested for thinking to murder someone. Hence no karma is involved for thinking and dreaming

Comment: I beg to differ.  Thoughts lead to actions.  A man con only become a saint when his thoughts are purified.  When a man keeps having lustful thoughts, he is "sinning".  When a man has violent thoughts of killing others to express his anger, he is "sinning".  Thoughts can 'harm' others, its just that you're not aware of it.  Thoughts eventually manifest in the real world.  The present chaotic world is a result of the sum of collective consciousness.  Aum. Jai Gurudeva