# Hymn or slokas for eliminating evil thoughts and cultivation positive and good thoughts?

Tags: shloka

I came to know by chanting "Aditya Hrudayam" slokas we can win over enemies and get good friends.

I would like to eliminate negative thoughts, ideas, emotions in our mind and stop generation of those(evil thoughts) in mind.

And at the same time I would like to cultivate continuous generation of positive and good thoughts and always mind filed with those good and positive thoughts, ideas and emotions in my mind.

Are there any Hymns, slokas those can help to achieve above stated objective?

Comment: Pick the name of your favourite God and keep chanting. Read up on how aversion therapy/negative stimulus works. Provide an equal or stronger opposing stimulus to the evil thoughts.

Comment: My answer here might provide some insights: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8459/does-chanting-holy-names-while-doing-worldly-duties-generate-any-punya-karma/9584#9584

Comment: Just chant Vishnu sahasranamam every day. It will help you in overcoming all the evil thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly recite Sudarsana Ashtakam daily  composed by Sarva tantra swatantra Acharya Nigamantha Maha Desikan. The link is given below--

stotraratna.sathyasaibababrotherhood.org/o14.htm

Sudarsana is chakra the mighty weapon. If you recite the sloka daily your negative thoughts and evil eyes will be warded off. Positive thoughts will culminate in your mind.

Perform one sudarsana homam. I did on Nov 1 2015 in my friends place in Hosur to eliminate the black magic. The evil [ghost] appeared in the homa kundam. All by the grace of Lord Sudarsana. Now he is a relieved person.

In the next sudarsana homa done on April 2 2016 in Chennai Lord sudarsana appeared [behind a chakra]  and right side 8 hands holding weapons in poornahuthi ash.

See the profile page for more details.

Jaya Jaya sri Sudarsana  Jaya Jaya sri Sudarsana

Answer (score 0):

The slokams with meaning--

Pratibhatasreni Bhishana,Varagunasthoma Bhushana
Janibhyasthana Taarana ,Jagadavasthaana Karana ,
Nikhiladushkarma Karsaana, Nigamasaddharma Darsana
Jaya Jaya Sri sudarsana ,Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana .               1

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who is fearsome to hoards of enemies of devotees
Who is ornament for all blessed actions,
Who helps one to cross sea of samsara,
Who stabilizes the entire universe,
Who cuts off accumulated sins of bad actions,
And who teaches righteous conduct.

Subhajagadrupa Mandana, Suraganathrasa Khandana
Satamakabrahma vandita ,Satapatabrahma Nandita   ,
Pratitavidvat Sapakshita ,Bhajata Ahirbudhnya Lakshita
Jaya jaya Sri Sudarsana ,Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .                 2

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who is the ornament of him who is Lord of universe,
Who removes the fear of all asuras towards devas,
Who is worshipped by Lord Brahma and hosts of others,
Who is worshipped by Sat Pada Brahmana,
Who is on the part of devotees for overcoming contestants,
And who is worshipped by Lord Shiva.

Sphutata -Dijjaala Pinjara,Pruthutarajwaala Panjara
Parigata Pratnavigraha ,Padutaraprajna Durgraha  ,
Praharana Grama Manditha, Parijana Thraana Panditha
Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana, Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .                 3

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who is surrounded by resplendent light like a halo,
Who is surrounded by forms of Vishnu,
Who is difficult for even great scholars to grasp,
And who helps devotees to cross problems.

Nijapatapreetha saddgana ,Nirupathispeetha Shad Guna
 Nigama NirvyuDa Vaibhava ,Nijapara Vyuha Vaibhava  ,
 Hari Haya Dweshi Daarana,Hara Pura Plosha Kaarana
 Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana , Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .              4

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who is firmly attached to righteous people,
Who is the natural home for six good assets,
Who took the form with a horse’s neck,
And who was the reason for destruction of the cities by Shiva.

Dhanuja visthaara Kartana,Janitamisraa Vikartana 
Dhanujavidya Nikartana, Bhajatavidya Nivatana ,
Amara drushtasva Vikrama,Samara Jushta Bramikrama
Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana, Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .                5

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who destroys the spread of asuras,
Who removes the sorrows of birth , aging and death,
Who wins over the art of war of asuras,
Who removes the false knowledge from his devotees,
Whose valour is praised by devas,
And who rotates in various ways in a war.

Prathimukhaaleeta Bandhura, Pruthumahaheti Danthura
Vikatamaaya Bahishkrutha ,Vividhamaalaa  Parishkrutha ,
Sthiramahaayantra Tantritha ,Dhruta Daya Tantra Yantrita
Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana , Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .               6

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who appeared with a fast forward gait,
And whose gait appeared very pretty,
Who is surrounded by several weapons,
And expels the illusions sent by  enemy in case of war,
Who decorates himself with several garlands,
Who wears mercy and blesses devotees,
Who worship him through tantra and yantras.

Mahita Sampath Sadhakshara ,Vihitasampath Shatakshara
Shatarachakra Pratisishtita ,Sakala Tattva Prathishtita ,
Vividha Sankalpaka Kalpaka,Vibhudhasankalpa Kalpaka
Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana, Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana  .            7

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who gives wealth of salvation to those who,
Chant your six lettered mantra,
Who gives incomparable wealth to those who,
Chant your six lettered mantra,
Who is available in yantra of six corners,
Who is a form in which all knowledge  exists,
Who is able to complete all deeds that you take up,
And who is the kalpaka tree fulfilling all wishes.

Bhuvana Netra Trayeemaya , Savanatejastrayeemaya
Niravadhisvaadhu Chinmaya, Nikhila Sakthe Jaganmaya  ,
Amita Viswakriyaamaya,Samitavishvagbhayaamaya 
Jaya Jaya Sri Sudarsana ,Jaya Jaya  Sri Sudarsana  .                8

Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Victory and Victory to you, oh, Sudarshana,
Who is the three Vedas which are the eye of the world,
Who is the form of the three fires of yagas,
Who is the eternal knowledge of true knowledge,
Who is a form of the power of universe,
Who is accomplisher of deeds that you take up,
And who destroys all fears occurring in the world.

Verse 9: Phala Sruthi 
Dwichatushkamidam Prabhoothasaaram patathaam Venkatanayaka Praneetham ,
Vishamepi Manorata: Pradhaavan na Vihanyeta Rataangadhuryagupta :  .

This octet which fulfills all desires,
Which gives the inner meaning of Lord Sudarshana,
Composed by Venkata Natha, if read,
Would fulfill desires, remove obstacles,
Because of the glorious boon granting powers of the Lord.